# Spring security login page in AnguarJS app

Tags: java, spring, angularjs, spring-security

I'm new to Spring Security and Angularjs. I'm trying to configure a login page in Spring security which is an Angular view. I run into a recursive loop with the below exception. I'm not sure how I can point Spring Security to recognize AngularJS view as a login page. FYI: the view has a HashBang. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
2014-07-19 23:08:20.343  INFO 2037 --- [bio-8080-exec-5] o.s.b.a.audit.listener.AuditListener     : AuditEvent [timestamp=Sat Jul 19 23:08:20 EDT 2014, principal=anonymousUser, type=AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE, data={type=org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException, message=Access is denied}]
```

I'm configuring security using Java configuration. My class looks like:

```
public class ApplicationSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/#/login").permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/fonts/**")
                .antMatchers("/images/**")
                .antMatchers("/scripts/**")
                .antMatchers("/styles/**")
                .antMatchers("/views/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        auth.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }
}
```

Comment: The browser does not send the # part of the url by default so I don't think this would work.

Comment: So, what can I do to make it work?

Comment: You could have a look at https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app . If done right it's not as simple as you think.

Comment: I am not sure about your particular issue, but just in case it helps, I was also having the `AuditListener` log message and in my case it was being generated by the auditing features of `spring-boot-actuator` .